# ParentMDI and axWindowsMediaPlayer fullscreen

Tags: fullscreen, mdiparent, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a parent form called Form1, and a child form called Form2.

Form2 has an embedded video, but when I try to set axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullscreen=true I got an error.

If I do not use Form2 as a child, it works ok. So how can I set fullscreen=true whit child form?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that I cannot do what I wanted, because the video is in a child form that is contained by a parent form. So I think the best answer is to embed the video in the parent form, and everything works great.